# How to handle @Ref from XSD in JSON Schema

Tags: jsonschema

Given the following basic example of a text element which references a para element and the para element itself references the para element.

I'm wondering if I'm correctly representing this in JSON Schema?

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <xs:element name="text">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="para"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="para">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="para"/>
      </xs:choice>
      <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I think that it has to be done with this style { "$ref": "#/definitions/diskDevice" },
http://json-schema.org/example2.html.

Is this correct?

```
{
 "id": "http://some.site.somewhere/entry-schema#",
 "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
 "title": "text",
 "type": "object",
 "properties": {
   "$ref": "#/definitions/para"
 },
 "definitions": {"para": {
  "required": true,
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
   "id": {
    "type": "string",
    "required": true
   },
   "$ref": "#/definitions/para"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: FYI, when using `$ref` in draft-4 JSON Schema, all other keywords in that object are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

That form of referencing is correct.  It is not the *only* way to organise things, but it is the way I would recommend.

You do have a bug in your schema, though - you have "$ref" directly inside "properties".  You are presumably not defining a *property* called "$ref" in your data, so is this meant to be inside another property declaration?

Comment: $Ref meant to be referencing the element  <xs:element name="para"> or "definitions": {"para":